# How can I give my figure more space?

Tags: tables, floats

I am making a table with some text underneath the columns.  I'd like to make it a figure, but when I do so, the text underneath the columns collides with the Figure label. See the attached photo

[image]

Code below:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}

        \begin{figure}[t]
            \centering
            % need the pifont package
            \begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l|l}
                %\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l|l}                                                                  
                \multicolumn{2}{c}{}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{True Label}&\\
                \cline{3-4}
                \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{Positive}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{Negative}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}\\
                %\cline{2-4}                                                                                 
                \hhline{~|---}
                \multirow{2}{*}{Predicted Label}& Positive & TP & FP ($\alpha$) &\ding{214} PPV\\
                %\cline{2-4}                                                                                 
                \hhline{~|---}
                & Negative & FN ($\beta$) & TN & \ding{214} NPV\\
                %\cline{2-4}                                                                                 
                \hhline{~|---}
                \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &
                \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{2em}{\vskip1ex\ding{215}\\ Se}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{2em}{\vskip1ex\ding{215}\\ Sp}}} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{}\\
            \end{tabular}
            \caption{Confusion Matrix}{A typical confusion matrix for a binary classifcation problem.}
            \label{confusionmatrix}

        \end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this is not an answer to your question, your example suggests that some macros I use may help you. They produce two way contingency tables like

[image]

The code is not as pretty or generic as it might be, but it is all I needed. (I'm sure I found most of the ideas in an answer on this site, which would surely have upvoted at the time - but I can't find the link now to put here.)

In the preamble:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% 
% Table packages
%
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% formatting contingency tables
% 
\newcommand{\thecondition}{to be renewed}
\newcommand{\theyes}{to be renewed}
\newcommand{\theno}{to be renewed}
\newlength{\tempdima}

\newcommand{\ctablehead}[3]{%
   \settowidth{\tempdima}{#1}% compute width needed
   \addtolength{\tempdima}{-\arraycolsep}% minus default column sep
   \renewcommand{\thecondition}{#1}
   \renewcommand{\theyes}{#2}
   \renewcommand{\theno}{#3}
}
\newcommand{\ctablebody}{%
\cline{3-5}
& &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\thecondition} & \\ 
& &   {\makebox[0.5\tempdima]{\theyes}} 
    & {\makebox[0.5\tempdima]{\theno}} 
    & {total} \\
\hline
}
```

In the document:

```
\ctablehead{chronic fatigue syndrome}{yes}{no}
{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}% for the vertical padding
\begin{tabular}{cc
|
S[table-format=3.0]
S[table-format=5.0]
|
S[table-format=6.0]
|
}
\ctablebody
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{\multirow{2}{*}{tested positive}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{yes} &  203  &   6802  & 7005 \\
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{}        &                
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{no} &  32  &  92963 & 92885 \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{}
 & total & 235 & 99765 & 100000 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}
```

Comment: This is beautiful!  A much better version than my own!

Answer (score 4):

The main error is your multirow which are spanning past the end of the table.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}

        \begin{figure}[t]
            \centering
            % need the pifont package
            \begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l|l}
                %\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l|l}                                                                  
                \multicolumn{2}{c}{}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{True Label}&\\
                \cline{3-4}
                \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{Positive}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{Negative}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}\\
                %\cline{2-4}                                                                                 
                \hhline{~|---}
                \multirow{2}{*}{Predicted Label}& Positive & TP & FP ($\alpha$) &\ding{214} PPV\\
                %\cline{2-4}                                                                                 
                \hhline{~|---}
                & Negative & FN ($\beta$) & TN & \ding{214} NPV\\
                %\cline{2-4}
                \hhline{~|---}                                                                     
                \multicolumn{2}{c}{\rule{0pt}{15pt}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\ding{215}}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\ding{215}} &\\
                \multicolumn{2}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{se}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{sp} &\\
            \end{tabular}
            \caption{Confusion Matrix}{A typical confusion matrix for a binary classifcation problem.}
            \label{confusionmatrix}

        \end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in your `\multirow` statements. They're meant to combine multiple rows, not to split an existing single row in multiple lines. If you use `\parbox` instead, you'll be fine.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}

        \begin{figure}[t]
           \centering
           % need the pifont package
           \begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l|l}
           %\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l|l}                                                                  
           \multicolumn{2}{c}{}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{True Label}&\\
           \cline{3-4}
           \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{Positive}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{Negative}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}\\
           %\cline{2-4}                                                                                 
           \hhline{~|---}
           \multirow{2}{*}{Predicted Label}& Positive & TP & FP ($\alpha$) &\ding{214} PPV\\
           %\cline{2-4}                                                                                 
           \hhline{~|---}
           & Negative & FN ($\beta$) & TN & \ding{214} NPV\\
           %\cline{2-4}                                                                                 
           \hhline{~|---}
           \multicolumn{2}{c}{}  &
           \multicolumn{1}{c}{\parbox{1em}{\ding{215}\\ Se}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\parbox{1em}{\ding{215}\\ Sp}}\\
           \end{tabular}
           \caption{Confusion Matrix}{A typical confusion matrix for a binary classifcation problem.}
           \label{confusionmatrix}

        \end{figure}


\end{document}
```